# Is it possible to have more than one setContentView in one class?

Tags: android, shapes

I am trying to print the rectangle shape and the main xml aswell as I want the shape and the figures, is this possible? If not how can I print a shape from java code and my main xml both on to my emulator? Thank you

```
package com.example.accel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RectShape;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AccelActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView = null;
    ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
    public static int x;
    public static int y;
    public static int z;
    private SensorManager sensorManager = null;
    TextView x1, y1, z1;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get a reference to a SensorManager
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);
        setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    // This method will update the UI on new sensor events
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent)
    {
        {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

                TextView tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
                TextView tvY= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
                TextView tvZ= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.z_axis);

                x = (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[0], 2); 
                y = (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[1], 2);
                z = (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[2], 2);

            }

         //   if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {

          //  }
        }
    }

    // I've chosen to not implement this method
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        // Register this class as a listener for the accelerometer sensor
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        // ...and the orientation sensor

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        // Unregister the listener
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    public class CustomDrawableView extends View
    {
        static final int width = 150;
        static final int height = 250;

        public CustomDrawableView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);

            mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
            mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
            mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);

        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {

            RectF rect = new RectF(AccelActivity.x, AccelActivity.y, AccelActivity.x + width, AccelActivity.y
                    + height); // set bounds of rectangle
            Paint p = new Paint(); // set some paint options
            p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, p);
            invalidate(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do that? A content view is supposed to be the delegate view to you controller. You can't have two. One has to be in the other one.

Comment: Maybe you want to inflate another xml layouts inside your main layout?

Comment: Because I want to the accelerometer values which is printed through the android main xml as well as the shape I have defined in the java code, I am not sure how to show both

Comment: Well your main.xml can contain multiple layouts. You can access each from your java code and do what you want with each one separately.

Comment: But i am trying to print the shape shown above and the xml together, I don't understand how to print both if there is only one setContentView

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can.

`setcontentview(anotherLayout)`, so you pring the new layout in your activity.

or you can define other elements in your mainLayout and you manipulate it by the function setVisibily

if you need elementA:

```
elementA = findViewById(R.id.elementA);
elementA.setVisibility(true);
```

and if you don't need it:

```
elementA.setVisibility(false);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am only trying to print one thing from main xml and the shape which is created in the java code, so they are separate, so i am trying to print both in the emulator